Will XCM ever support transferring assets from Polkadot parachains to Kusama parachains, and vice versa?
The polkadot wiki describes XCM as a messaging format and a language used to communicate between consensus systems.
XCM as a language is expressive enough to describe such a transfer between a Polkadot parachain and a Kusama parachain.
But is it possible in reality without a bridge?
